# What is different about Hard Mode?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb, wrath-of-the-lamb-eternal

Binding of Isaac got an update last night, it now contains a "Hard Mode".

I've started a game with it, and so far I've noticed a couple new types of champions, more champions and a bomb that turned into a live bomb when I tried to pick it up. I'm not sure if all of this is caused by Hard Mode or just by the update (I assume the more champions is caused by Hard Mode though)

Are there any other differences? Less drops? Champion types unique to Hard Mode? Special bosses? Other rooms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Champion type is called **Eternal**, and are tinted white (like *Eternal flies* sprite). They have increased health and their attacks are more powerful and faster. They also shoot more bullets than usual, and even homing bullets.
As far as I can see the Eternal version is exclusive of Hard Mode, they can be both bosses and random enemies. If you defeat an Eternal Boss in addition to the usual pedestal item you get an Eternal Heart as reward.

Here's further info I've found on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/34mv0n/wrath_of_the_lamb_eternal_update_is_out/).

- If you roll *The Dice* it sometimes makes no item appear at all.
- Some *Eternal* bosses, like *Gurdy Jr.*, now track you when they charges and they also have regenerating health.
- *Eternal Peep* has now more than 2 wandering (and annoying) eyes.
- > *Mom's Heart* and *It Lives* have earned the ability to move.
- Bombs usually become Troll Bombs when you pick them up (as you wrote).
- Added one [new trinket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Ioz.jpg) called **Game Squid**: its effect is making each X'th tear have Gish's slow effect. It's basically a trinket version of *Ball of Tar* without the creep.
- There should be a new type of room, **Eternal Arena**:

  > It works the same way as a boss challenge room, however it takes items from the angel room pool and also spawns 2 hearts when you pick the item up. Also the bosses are all the diabolical white alts. Don't know how much health or w/e you need to get in though.

[image]

As a side note, the amount of bullets some of the Eternal enemies fire is enough to slow the game down dramatically. The old good Flash.